# Minimum Spanning Tree in a Complete Graph

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory, trees

We generate a complete euclidean graph by taking **N** random points from a **limited** (1.0 x 1.0 square) 2D space, connecting them all together (*complete* graph) and giving the edges weights proportional (or equal) to the euclidean distance in space between the two incident points (*euclidean* graph).

If the random point generator in uniform, then if N is big enough it should be visible, that the points form a semi-regular grid of points.

I am to generate a Minimum Spanning Tree of such a graph (using Prim's algorithm).

The question is:
**Should I expect any characteristic patterns of the tree?**

Kindest regards,
Elmes

Comment: The Math Overflow question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38824/what-upper-bounds-are-known-for-the-diameter-of-the-minimum-spanning-tree-of-n may be relevant here.